# NSPredicate Boolean Value Reversed

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

This is really weird. Here is the predicate I am using to get a "list" with selected property is set to NO:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"selected == %@", @(NO)]]
```

However the result is an object with the selected property = 1. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

The selected property was not saved in the first place because I set it in `didSave` callback. I "re-save" the object but for some reasons the selected property is no longer updates and when I checked the `hasChanged` property of the context, I found it to be NO.

Comment: is "selected" NSNumber?

Comment: As it turns out, the problem is not the predicate. The object is not saved correctly. checkout this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697440/core-data-re-saving-object-in-didsave