# Core Data - Re-saving Object in didSave

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have to check for certain properties after saving the object to the database (I need to make sure first that it's saved on disk). So, I thought that the `didSave` method of `NSManagedObject` is the best place to do so.

However, after checking for these properties *and* changing some of them, I want to *re-save* the object. So, I call the managed object context to save the object *one more time*. (I made heavy testing to make sure I won't get into an infinite loop).

Now, the problem is the managed object context doesn't perform the second save. How did I know that? Well, first I checked the `hasChanged` property of the context for the second save and it returns no. Also, the didSave method is not called one more time due to the re-save.

Is there something I am doing wrong? What's wrong with my algorithm?

**Note:**

I considered `willSave` at the beginning but as it turned out, `willSave` is called before validation. The object may not be saved on disk after all. I need to perform my check and new setting *after* saving to disk.

Comment: What you're describing runs counter to the description in the documentation, where it states that changes made in didSave will dirty the context. Can you include some sample code in your question?

Comment: You are correct, @jrturton. I was mistaken. willSave is called after validation and is the good place for my case. The test project I used to check for willSave was buggy.